# Loading Windows.phone.Speech into PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-phone-8

So I have been poking around looking for some way to use Cortana (mainly her voice although the commands would be nice too) in windows powershell.
yes I am aware speech recognition and speech Synthesis is quite easy to do with system.speech. that's not my goal

so far I can load winRT components with this syntax:

[FullTypeNameIncludingNameSpace,NameSpace,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] 
thanks to this website here: http://karlprosser.com/coder/2014/04/06/winrt-and-powershell-part-1/

looking through the windows API found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx

I see that there are both 
Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis
And
windows.phone.speech.synthesis

Now I tried Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis and it seems to work; However, it seems to be almost the same as system.speech
The code:

returns the same voices used by system.speech

this leaves me to assume that cortana in windows 10 is using windows.phone.speech.synthesis
and here voice is located elsewhere.
the trouble is, when trying to use windows.phone.speech.synthesis with
[windows.phone.speech.synthesis.installedvoices,Windows.Phone.Speech.Synthesis,ContentType=WindowsphoneRuntime]

I get the following error:
Unable to find type [windows.phone.speech.synthesis.installedvoices,Windows.Phone.Speech.Synthesis, 
ContentType=WindowsphoneRuntime]. Make sure that the assembly that contains this type is loaded.

This comes up with anything related to windows.phone.
i would guess that it would not be available on the PC, but then how/where is cortana located for windows 10 and how can she be accessed? or am I just referencing the component wrong?